# MSBuild thinks my .NET solution has two projects named _nuget

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

We have a Windows Forms solution in VS 2010 that has 7 projects.

A couple of days ago one of our developers checked in a changeset that accidentally added several projects from another solution. The other solution is one that contains Web Forms and Web MVC projects and is a VS 2012 solution.

So this morning I set about undoing the damage by reinstating the solution file from immediately before Monday's check-in. And it builds and runs correctly in Visual Studio but fails to build using MSBuild triggered by TFS.

The error states:

The solution file has two projects named "_nuget".

The weird thing is that when I examine the solution file in a text editor there are no projects at all named _nuget.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you 100% the entire source tree is exactly the same as before the offending checkin? If so, the problem would have existed already. Else do a clean checkout and work your way up from there.

Comment: Yes, we are positive it is identical. Thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for anyone else who might suffer from this in the future.

We needed to edit the build profile, Process Section, Clean Workspace item. After changing it from Outputs to All the build succeeded.

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tya0U.jpg)